# How to click OK button after entering text in cke editor

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am facing issue while operating cke editor.

Please find image of cke editor:

[image of CKE editor (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgLaM.png)

I am able to switch to editor and enter text but getting error when I try to click on OK button.

Below is my code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.cke_wysiwyg_frame.cke_reset")));
    WebElement body = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.tagName("body")));
    body.sendKeys("Adding dummy product"); 
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  WebElement element4 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//img[@alt='Ok']")));
   element4.click();
```

Here is the HTML code for Ok button:

```
 <a onclick="
                        try {valueSelectors['tile389'].submit(); }catch (e) {}; return false;"
                    id="tile392_0"
                    actionName="SET"
                        href="#" class="" ><img src="theme/configuratorSiemens/images/btn/btnSet.png" alt="Ok" title="Ok" />
                         </a>
```

Please find error message:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected 
 condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: 
 //img[@alt='Ok'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
 at 

 org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:232)
    at Initiate.CameleonStart.manualPositin(CameleonStart.java:1002)
    at Initiate.ExecutionFlow.TestCases(ExecutionFlow.java:31)
    at Initiate.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:52)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //img[@alt='Ok']
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'P3B-BQHT7R1', ip: '10.222.132.78', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the correct way to do this.

Also let me know if more HTML is needed.

Please find below HTML for CKE editor

[CKE html](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AlB69WNspp0thy8mKBSYg5FXUpK_)

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the ok button inside Iframe or on the main page?

Comment: It is not inside iframe.

Comment: I have added html for cke editor.

Comment: Could you add a `Thread.sleep(1000);` statement after your `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried. But its not working. Getting error "Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //img[@alt='Ok']".

Comment: So, the error message has changed now?

Comment: No, its same as previous. I just highlighted one line. Its same as the one I added in question.

Comment: Can you replace your xpath as **//a[@id='tile392_0']/img** and see if it works?

Comment: Actually 'tile392_0' is dynamic value. This value will change each time we run our test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above issue resolved with beow code:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.cke_wysiwyg_frame.cke_reset")));
            WebElement body = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.tagName("body")));
            body.sendKeys(TestData.get("manPostn_desc"));
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Thank you.